# Power BI Enterprise Gateway

Tags: wcf, powerbi

I have an issue with installing the Power BI Enterprise Gateway. Could you help me?

- Installation of the Gateway is succesful
- Log in to Power BI succesful
- Gateway is created in Power BI
- I get the error "**Error updating gateway configuration**" with the following stack trace. Below the most interesting part of the stack trace:
  Error updating gateway configuration. ----> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: **An extension of name 'netTcpRelayBinding' already appears in extension collection. Extension names must be unique. (C:\Program Files\Power BI Enterprise Gateway\Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.DLL.config line 15)**
- I tried to uninstall PowerBI Enterprise Gateway, cleared everything that wasn't automatically deleted and reinstalled it.
- I restarted the service
- I tried renaming the 'netTcpRelayBinding' into 'mynetTcpRelayBinding' but something else refers to it, so that is not possible

Full stack trace

```
Failed to update gateway details.  Please try again.
```

Error updating gateway configuration.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.InternalContracts.IGatewayConfigurationService.UpdateGatewayConfiguration(UpdateGatewayConfigurationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayClient.GatewayConfigurationClient.UpdateGatewayConfiguration(UpdateGatewayConfigurationRequest request)An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Diagnostics.CouldNotUpdateGatewayConfigurationException: Error updating gateway configuration. ----> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: **An extension of name 'netTcpRelayBinding' already appears in extension collection. Extension names must be unique. (C:\Program Files\Power BI Enterprise Gateway\Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.DLL.config line 15)**
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.Get(String name)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.get_Bindings()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Configuration.ConfigurationFileCustomLoading.GetBinding(String name)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayCoreSettings.get_GatewayTransferServiceBinding()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.GatewayServiceHost.GetTransferServiceHost(IGatewayTransferService serviceInstance, CredentialReference`1 serviceBusDetails)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.ServiceHostController.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.ServiceHostController.d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.ServiceHostController.StopHandle.d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.GatewayServiceHost.d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.GatewayServiceHost.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Common.TaskUtils.ExtendedWait(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.GatewayServiceHost.UpdateConfiguration(GatewayConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.ServiceModel.GatewayConfigurationService.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Common.Diagnostics.PipelineTelemetryService.ExecuteInActivity(PipelineActivityType pipelineActivityType, Action action)
   at SyncInvokeUpdateGatewayConfiguration(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it has something to do with the installation of ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) on that same server. Looks like PowerBI Desktop and ADFS don't go together very well.

Comment: Thanks for posting back your findings. Can you click the checkmark to mark this the answer?